# Read CDPOS/CDHDR Sap tables using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, saprfc

I am trying to read sap change log using rfc + vbs as buffer. 
I know that I need to use `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS` and `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_POSITIONS` functions to do this, but have not found any research how to do this properly with the help of vbscript.

I have already found out how to read normal tables using `BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE` but it doesn’t work with CDPOS...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to use VBscript to integrate with SAP, you will go through RFC channel using SAP NWRFC library or SAP .Net Connector 3.0, and the SAP functions or BAPIs you can call must be remote enabled. Unfortunately, the two functions, `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS` and `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_POSITIONS`, are not remote enabled. I could imagine `CDPOS` is difficult for you because `CDPOS` has wide fields which cannot be processed by `BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE`.

Once we are aligned with the objective challenges, there are two options to help you move forward:

1. Write your own custom "Z" function module, which is remote enabled, and call `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_HEADERS` and `CHANGEDOCUMENT_READ_POSITIONS` inside the function;
2. Use third party commercial library (our company AecorSoft developed such ADO.NET compliant library for SAP integration).

I would suggest you explore #1 first. You can follow this blog https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/09/how-to-use-dotnet-connector-nco-inside-vba/ to get started.

Comment: I think that’ll work! But the problem is that due to corporate reasons we are not allowed to write own functions in sap BAPI... If you know any other way to access CDPOS that would be perfect:)

Answer (score 0):

Dunno about `BBP_RFC_READ_TABLE` but `RFC_READ_TABLE` perfectly reads `CDPOS`

[image]

If you need to header-based query you will need 2 sequential reads: first for `CDHDR` headers and the second for positions, constructing second query from the first.

Comment: Why I should leave FIELDS empty? Of course it throws BUFFER_EXCEEDS. If OP wants to fulfill his task he should read only **necessary** fields and by packages. Do you always use `SELECT *` in your developments? If so, you are a junior still. Don't promote your connector so aggressively, standard solutions are always preferable

Comment: Point well taken. You are right. Depending on the requirement, OP does not have to fetch all fields. I was thinking VALUE_NEW and VALUE_OLD would be the desired ones but speculation shall not be the assumption. I will remove my previous comment.